# Are there other app:layout_behavior predefined values?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, androidx

In [design support lib post](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) I saw `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`.

It makes `AppBarLayout` not overlap the contents from under it. Even though there is no such line in my `string.xml`.

Are there any other predefined behaviors and when is it put to string file?

Answer (score -1):

The behavior is defined in another file that does not directly belong to your project and apparently, there are not other default `layout_behavior`.

You can see that the final used string is this one:

```
<string name="appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" translatable="false">com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior</string>
```

If you would like to inspect the file, mine was located under the following path (MacOS):

`/Users/{username}/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/material-1.1.0-alpha02.aar/903dc3574983c63db2914223f13b7f8e⁩/res/values/values.xml`

Note that `903dc3574983c63db2914223f13b7f8e`might be different in your case